# Excel VBA: Stop userform from reopening

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have two userforms in a worksheet that open when yes or no are respectively selected from a dropdown list in cell G5. 
Everytime a user continues to enter data somwhere else in the worksheet (in cells other than G5), the userform reopens/reappears though.
Is there a way to ensure the userform is only opened when the value in G5 changes?

(Application.EnableEvents = True needs to be on as there are more userforms further down the sheet.)

Thanks in advance for any help!

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.EnableEvents = True
Set Target = Range("G5")
Application.EnableEvents = False

If Target = "No" Then

    Form1.Show

ElseIf Target = "Yes" Then

    From2.Show

End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If Target.Address = "$G$5" Then ...

Comment: I don't think `Set Target = Range("G5")` does what you think it does... you are not testing if the range is G5 but changing the cell referred by Target.

Comment: Seems like that was the problem indeed! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Target.Address = "$G$5" Then

        If Target = "No" Then

            Form1.Show

        ElseIf Target = "Yes" Then

            From2.Show

        End If

    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```